# How do I condition the build of one target on the execution of another target's binary product?

Tags: cmake

I have a test code for my c project, which is built as part of my cmake project.
In order to run properly, the SW needs an input binary file.
The binary file is created from a designated .json file (which is in the test's directory) using a separate executable which is also part of the same cmake project.
Before the test is run (i.e. when building it) I need the bin-building executable to be built (easy enough with target dependency), but I also need the resulting executable to run with my .json as input.
What cmake functions enable this?

I tried building a custom command with the binary as output, but the test target doesn't know it needs the binary in order to run, can't accept the binary as a source, and a simple "add_dependancy" resulted in errors.

```
function(create_binary input_json dst_bin)
    if (IS_WINDOWS)
        set(exe_path ${OUTPUT_BIN_DIR}/BinaryGenerator.exe)
    elseif(IS_LINUX)
        set(exe_path ${OUTPUT_BIN_DIR}/BinaryGenerator)
    endif()
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT  ${dst_bin}
                       COMMAND ${exe_path} ${input_json} ${dst_bin}
                       DEPENDS ${exe_path} ${dst_bin}
                       COMMENT STATUS "Creating bin file ${dst_bin} from ${input_json}"
            )
endfunction(create_binary)

create_binary(InputParams.json ${OUTPUT_BIN_DIR}/InputParams.bin)

add_executable(MySwTest TestFile.cpp TestFile.h)

add_dependencies(${OUTPUT_BIN_DIR}/InputParams.bin)
```

I expected cmake to place a target dependency between my test target and the bin creator target, and also on the existence of the test's bin file, thus running the custom command in order to create it.
The actual output from cmake is "The dependency target InputParams.bin doesn't exist". I assume this is because "add_dependency" is meant to work only with targets.
Would adding a custom target including my binary solve this?

Comment: `add_dependencies` adjust dependencies **between targets**. So not only every its argument should be a *target* ("Would adding a custom target including my binary solve this?" - yes), but it should be called at least with **2 arguments** for have any effect. What is the second argument to that command? Other issues: 1. Having `${dst_bin}` in both OUTPUT and DEPENDS clauses is weird. 2. Is `${exe_path}` denotes path to the executable **target** created with `add_executable`? If so, place name of the target instead, and CMake will transform it to the path and add proper dependency automatically.

Comment: @Tsyvarev
1. I'd guess:
```cmake
add_custom_target(GenerateBin DEPENDS ${dst_bin})
```
2. Probably right, I should leave it only in the output.
3. exe_path indeed denotes the path, but I need the actual executable for the custom command, the target won't do for that...

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed solvable by defining a custom target that depends on the resulting binary.

When adding a custom command, the actual command is only called if the command's OUTPUT file is needed for another target - so if it's a source file, it will be called.

My command's output is a generated binary, and therefore is not a source file for my target.
However, using `add_custom_target()` I can create a target dependent on said bin file, and create a dependency between the end target and my custom target.

The working code for the above looks like this:

```
set(PARAMS_NAME InputParams)
set(INPUT_JSON ${PARAMS_NAME}.json)
set(DST_BIN ${PARAMS_NAME}.bin)

if (IS_WINDOWS)
    set(EXE_PATH ${OUTPUT_BIN_DIR}/BinaryGenerator.exe)
elseif(IS_LINUX)
    set(EXE_PATH ${OUTPUT_BIN_DIR}/BinaryGenerator)
endif()

add_custom_command(OUTPUT  ${DST_BIN}
                   COMMAND ${EXE_PATH} ${INPUT_JSON} ${DST_BIN}
                   DEPENDS BinaryGenerator ${INPUT_JSON}
                   COMMENT STATUS "Creating bin file ${DST_BIN} from ${INPUT_JSON}"
    )
add_custom_target(${PARAMS_NAME}BinGenerated DEPENDS ${DST_BIN})

add_executable(MySwTest TestFile.cpp TestFile.h)

add_dependencies(MySwTest ${PARAMS_NAME}BinGenerated)
```

By adding a dependency between MySwTest and my custom target, I ensure that the command generating my binary is called for each build.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Thanks for your input! Helped put me on the right track!